# I need help in a query to my db

Tags: php, mysql, for-loop, mysqli

I'm here with a problem in a query . Need to insert emails in my database but are not repeated . The email 's are entered separated by commas or semicolons. I leave the code I have so far:

```
$separador = $_POST['separador'];
$listemails= explode($separador, $_POST['emails']);
$count = count($listemails);
for($i=0; $i < $count; $i++){
    $check = $connection -> query("SELECT * FROM emails WHERE email_endereco='$listemails[$i]'") or die($connection -> error);
    if($res = $check -> fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
        ...
    }
    $result = $connection -> query("INSERT INTO emails VALUES(NULL, '".$listemails[$i]."')") or die($connection -> error);
    $lastid = $connection -> insert_id;
    $connection -> query("INSERT INTO emails_lists VALUES(NULL,'$lastid','$l')") or die($connetion -> error);
}
```

What I miss the place where I have the ellipsis?

Comment: what you're looking for is 'continue;'  It will skip back to the top of the for-loop for emails already in the database.

Comment: Please Please read up about SQL Injection and Parameters. This is a very poor way to do it

Comment: @Milney This question is already resolved :)

Comment: you should still seriously (and especially so If the code is in use in a real website) read up on SQL Injection and parameters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Already got :D !
I changed the email field in the db for primary key and then changed the code to make it so:

```
for($i=0; $i < $count; $i++){
    $str .= "(NULL,'".$listemails[$i]."')".($i < $count - 1 ? "," : "");
}
$result = $connection -> query("INSERT IGNORE INTO emails VALUES ".$str) or die($connection -> error);
```

Here I leave the answer to if I can help someone else!